# YouTube API onPlayerReady is Never Getting Called

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, youtube, slim-lang

Follow [this tutorial](https://developers.google.com/youtube/iframe_api_reference), I have been trying to integrate the YouTube API into my website. Specifically, when a button is pressed I want to play a video hosted on YouTube in fullscreen mode. Unfortunately, I can't even get the code given in that tutorial to work.

I'm using Slim for markup so I added an empty div with the ID of player as the tutorial suggests

```
.body  
  .player
```

I then added this javascript at the end of my markup

```
  $(document).ready(
    function() {
      loadYoutubeAPI();
    });
```

Which should start the chain of calling these functions

```
function loadYoutubeAPI() {
    var tag = document.createElement('script');
    tag.src = "https://www.youtube.com/iframe_api";
    var firstScriptTag = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
    firstScriptTag.parentNode.insertBefore(tag, firstScriptTag);
}

var player;
function onYouTubeIframeAPIReady() {
    player = new YT.Player('player', {
        height: '390',
        width: '640',
        videoId: 'M7lc1UVf-VE',
        events: {
        'onReady': onPlayerReady,
        'onStateChange': onPlayerStateChange
        }
    });
}

function onPlayerReady(event) {
    event.target.playVideo();
}

var done = false;
function onPlayerStateChange(event) {
    if (event.data == YT.PlayerState.PLAYING && !done) {
        setTimeout(stopVideo, 6000);
        done = true;
    }
}

function stopVideo() {
    player.stopVideo();
}
```

However, the chain of calls stops before onPlayerReady fires and I can't figure out why.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From what I can see, it seems as though your issue may be in the player div seems to be of the class player and from what I can see in the tutorial, its looking for an div with player id. so something like the following may work:

```
.body
    #player
```

I am not 100% familiar with Slim so you may need to mark this up differently.

Comment: @NickGilbert Nice! I am glad things worked out for you.

Comment: Well, almost. One last issue http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40164701/iframe-has-no-defined-request-full-screen-method